# How do I mark/unmark, write as Accepted/Rejected/Cancelled a text annotation using iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, pdf, properties, itext, pdf-annotations

I'm working with iTextSharp on Visual Studio. I created a Pdfannotation like that:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(stamper.Writer, rect, "Author", "I write my text", true, "New Paragraph");
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, 1);
```

So my annotation contents a text "I write my text". 
When I go on Adobe Acrobat Reader to open my pdf, and when I click on the button "Comment" to see all the comments I wrote on my pdf, I see my comment and near to my comment "I write my text", I see  a little square that I can check or uncheck.
This is a little Checkbox which was automatically created when I created my Pdf annotation. I didn't create it by myself.

I would like to check or uncheck this little checkbox using iTextSharp.

I thought about doing that, but it doesn't work :

```
  RadioCheckField checkbox = new RadioCheckField(stamper.Writer, rect, "bonjour", "on");
        checkbox.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
        checkbox.Checked = true;
        PdfFormField field = checkbox.CheckField;

        annotation.Put(PdfName.A, field);
```

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thank you a lot!

Have a good day! :)

Comment: You are creating a text annotation. You can't check or uncheck a text annotation. Please show us how you're creating a check box.

Comment: If you look on Adobe Acrobat Reader, you'll see that after adding you're annotation you can choose to check it or uncheak it. I can't add a picture, the website does'nt allow me to (because I'm new on it).

Comment: Your question is inaccurate. You are creating a text annotation (aka sticky note). You can change the representation to a check mark as shown [here](http://itextpdf.org/documents/stickynote.png), but that's not what you're asking. You are asking to check/uncheck a check box. A check box is a form field represented by a widget annotation, *not* a text annotation. Be more accurate!

Comment: On the picture you are showing to me, in the column  "Comments Lists" I see your name "Bruno" and on the right of that i see a little square, that's the checkbox I'm speaking about, and that I would like to check with itextSharp

Comment: Do you know the meaning of that check box? Please explain!

Comment: In my office they use it as "this annotation is approved", so I would like to know how to check or uncheck this "checkbox" with iTextSharp. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Set the check box using Acrobat. Compare the PDF with the unchecked annotation with the PDF with the checked annotation using RUPS. Update the annotation accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was somewhat confusion because of the terminology "check/uncheck" in the context of a text (or Sticky Note) annotation. The correct terminology would have been: *How to I mark/unmark a text annotation?*

Checking/unchecking immediately makes us think about check boxes, but the following screen shot shows what is meant when we talk about marking a text annotation:

[image]

Marking a text annotation isn't a matter of checking a check box. Marking a text annotation is done by adding a hidden "In Reply To" (IRT) annotation. See [How to add an "In Reply To" annotation?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-reply-annotation) on the official site for more information about "In Reply To" annotations.

I've adapted the [AddInReplyTo](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/annotation-reply-another-annotation#1135-addinreplyto.java) example with the [AddMarked](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/annotation-reply-another-annotation#1852-addmarked.java) as result:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    PdfDictionary sticky = annots.getAsDict(0);
    PdfArray stickyRect = sticky.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
    PdfDictionary popup = annots.getAsDict(1);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
    Rectangle stickyRectangle = new Rectangle(
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(0).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(1).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(3).floatValue()
    );
    PdfAnnotation replySticky = PdfAnnotation.createText(
            writer, stickyRectangle, "Bruno", "Marked set by Bruno", false, "Comment");
    replySticky.put(PdfName.IRT, annots.getAsIndirectObject(0));
    replySticky.put(PdfName.STATE, new PdfString("Marked"));
    PdfNumber n = sticky.getAsNumber(PdfName.F);
    replySticky.put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(n.intValue() | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN));
    replySticky.put(new PdfName("StateModel"), new PdfString("Marked"));
    stamper.addAnnotation(replySticky, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

The example is in Java, but it should be fairly easy to adapt it to C#. It's important to know that marking the original annotation `sticky` is done by adding an extra annotation `replySticky`. The difference with an ordinary IRT annotation, is that we are going to hide the annotation by adding `FLAGS_HIDDEN` to the flags of the annotation. We also set the `/State` to `Marked` and the `/StateModel` to `Marked`.

This code turns [hello_sticky_note.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/hello_sticky_note.pdf) into [hello_marked.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/annotations/cmp_hello_marked.pdf) as was requested, but there's a catch! The check box will only be visible if you are logged in as user "Bruno". This check box is for personal use only.

If you want others to see a review status, you shouldn't use the "Marked" feature. Instead you should use "Review". This is poorly documented in ISO-32000. See the table with title "Additional entries specific to a text annotation":

[image]

This table refers to the table with title "Annotation States":

[image]

We have used the combination *StateModel = Marked; State = Marked*, which means that the annotation has been marked by the user. I didn't find any reference in the spec that this mark is only visible on the machine of the user who marked the document.

After discovering this, I've created the [AddAccepted](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2188#1854-addaccepted.java) example:

```
PdfAnnotation replySticky = PdfAnnotation.createText(
        writer, stickyRectangle, "Bruno", "Accepted by Bruno", false, "Comment");
replySticky.put(PdfName.IRT, annots.getAsIndirectObject(0));
replySticky.put(PdfName.STATE, new PdfString("Accepted"));
PdfNumber n = sticky.getAsNumber(PdfName.F);
replySticky.put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(n.intValue() | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN));
replySticky.put(new PdfName("StateModel"), new PdfString("Review"));
stamper.addAnnotation(replySticky, 1);
stamper.close();
```

This example is identical to what we had before, except that we now use the combination: *StateModel = Review; State = Accepted*. As you can tell from the "Annotation states" table, other possible options for the State are "Rejected", "Cancelled", "Completed" and "None" (which is the default value).

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, a green check mark appears in the comments panel. It shows "Bruno Accepted" on a computer where the logged in user isn't Bruno. You can check this for yourself here: [hello_accepted.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/annotations/cmp_hello_accepted.pdf)

Comment: Than you for your answer! Why do you use this line : 

    replySticky.Put(PdfName.IRT, annots.GetAsIndirectObject(0));

Because when I write it, I don't see my comment answer "Marked set by Bruno" anymore. And when I don't write it, my answer is here but the problem persists : my answer is not marked.

Comment: Don't copy my example literally. If you remove the `IRT` key, you don't understand my answer. `IRT` stands for **In Reply To.** The value of this entry is a reference to the annotation that needs to be marked. In my simple example, it's easy: there's only one annotation, so I can take the first one `annots.getAsIndirectObject(0)`. In your case, you have to change `0` into the index of the annotation you want to mark. Start by trying the example on hello_sticky_note.pdf. Examine what happens and adapt the simple example to match your needs.

Comment: I copied your code with your pdf example hello_sticky_note.pdf and it doesn't work. The answer "Marked set by Bruno" doesn't appear and the mark doesn't too

Comment: The answer "Marked set by Bruno" should not appear: it is `HIDDEN`! The mark should appear and appears (when done correctly). When I run the code in Java, it works as expected. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but it works for me. This is my proof: http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/annotations/cmp_hello_marked.pdf

Comment: I save the proof and I open it with Adobe Reader but I don't see any mark

Comment: That's because you are logged in as a different user. That check mark only works on the machine of the user that checked it. Maybe your question is still wrong. Maybe you don't want to *mark* the annotation. Maybe you want to *review* the annotation. I've updated my answer. The next time you ask a question, you should be more helpful by being more clear. I've spent several hundreds of dollars worth of my time on your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried your new code with the “Review” features and it’s perfect. I didn’t know that the mark was only visible by the user who wrote it, so the “Review” features are perfectly adapted for what I want to do. Thank you again !